# Cast C Struct in Lua/LuaJIT

Tags: c++, struct, lua, luajit

I have this C struct:

```
typedef struct { double x, y; } point_t;
```

and I need to send a `point_t` variable to Lua and change its values and then return it to C.
The first problem that I have is to cast it in Lua. How can it be done ?

main.c

```
point_t ponto;

ponto.x = 0; ponto.y = 0;

lua_getglobal(L, "jit"); //Get variavel with function
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, &ponto);
lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0);

point_t *pontop = (point_t*)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
```

test.lua

```
 jit = function(num)
    local ffi = require("ffi")
    ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct { double x, y; } point_t;
    ]]

    local point
    local mt = {}
    point = ffi.metatype("point_t", mt)

    local a = point(3, 4)
    print(a.x, a.y)
    b = ffi.cast("point_t*",num)
    b.x = 10
    b.y = 20
    return b
end
```

The local variable `a` is created with `point_t` type, how can I cast `b` to use it like `a` ?

Comment: Don't mix lua C API with luajit's FFI mechanism. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18822678/234175

Comment: yes, I came up with that question. Is it even possible ?

Comment: For your case above, you can probably get away with `return num`. The main thing is after doing `ffi.cast`, `b` is now a 'cdata' and ffi doesn't provide a way to back cast into a userdata. The lua-api doesn't understand 'cdata'.

Comment: but it's important to change values in the struct, that's the point of all this.

Comment: `b` and `num` both refer to the same object. Changing the fields through `b` will be reflected in `num`. Doing a `print(b, num)` for example, will show the same address but one is treated as 'cdata' while the other is 'userdata'.

Comment: but lua doesn't know how to access the fields inside `num` in order to change it, it's just a pointer

Comment: But you're not accessing the fields through `num`, you're doing it through `b`. The `b = ffi.cast("point_t *", num)` is sort of like `lua_touserdata` but from lua space made possible by luajit's ffi. Changing the fields using `b` will automatically change it in `num` also since they're pointing to the same underlying object. I'm not sure where the confusion is.